# How to display Hidden column data when a row of GridView is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, popup

I have a gridview in which fourth column is hidden which has a panel.

Earlier I showed the hidden panel when I mouse over a particular row using AJAX HoverMenuExtender

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender" runat="server" PopupControlID="PopupMenu"
                                        TargetControlID="grdMainData" PopupPosition="Center" OffsetY="30" OffsetX="10"
                                        PopDelay="50" HoverCssClass="popupHover">
                                    </asp:HoverMenuExtender>
                                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PopupMenu" CssClass="popupMenu">
    <asp:Label ID="lblVDetails" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("vDetails")%>'/>
                              </asp:Panel>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Its working perfectly fine...

But now I want to put a button in gridview and display the popup when I click on the button

Means when I click on row1 button I should get row1's Panel in popup, I don't want any page refreshes

Is it possible using any JavaScript or jQuery or AJAX Extenders

Is it possible or not?

This is My GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdMainData" runat="server" CellPadding="3" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
                        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" Width="900" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grdMainData_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Curriculum" DataField="Curriculum" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" />
                            <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Code" DataField="Code" />--%>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button type="button" ID="btnCode" class="button-code" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Code") %>'/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Stage" DataField="Stage" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnCode" PopupControlID="PopupMenu" DropShadow="true" CancelControlID="lnkClose">
                                    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

                                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PopupMenu" CssClass="popupMenu">
    <asp:Label ID="lblVDetails" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("vDetails").ToString().Replace("\u2022","<br/> \u2022")%>'/>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClose" runat="server">Close</asp:LinkButton>
                              </asp:Panel>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using AJAX Extenders. I suggest to just keep using it.
The AJAX control toolkit's ModalPopUpExtender  would be perfect for what you need. 
you can check it's demo and documenation [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx).

**Update:**
use this markup

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender 
     ID="ModalPopupExtender" 
     runat="server"
     TargetControlID="btnCode"
     PopupControlID="PopupMenu">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: i have panel inside the gridview how should i map that panel to modalpopup

Comment: Looking at your markup you are referencing the grid, when you should reference the button ID of the button that would call the extender.

Comment: Hey sorry i already changed that thing in my code forgot to update here

Problem solved but not the good way

Comment: Wow, that's not a very gracious fallback :( odd thing though. it works on my machine, i'm not sure what's causing the error you are encountering.